# Future and Option in for comprehension in slick

Tags: scala, slick

I pretty new in using slick and now I faced with the issue how to retrieve some data from two tables.
I have one table

```
class ExecutionTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[ExecTuple](tag, "execution") {
  val id: Rep[String] = column[String]("id")
  val executionDefinitionId: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("executionDefinitionId")
  // other fields are omitted

  def * = ???
}
```

and another table

```
class ServiceStatusTable(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[(String, Option[String])](tag, "serviceStatus") {
  def serviceId: Rep[String] = column[String]("serviceId")
  def detail: Rep[String] = column[String]("detail")

  def * = (serviceId, detail.?)
}
```

In Dao I convert data from this two tables to a business object

```
case class ServiceStatus(
  id: String, 
  detail: Option[String] = None, //other fields
)
```

like this

```
private lazy val getServiceStatusCompiled = Compiled {
  (id: Rep[String], tenantId: Rep[String]) =>
  for {
    exec   <- getExecutionById(id, tenantId)
    status <- serviceStatuses if exec.id === status.serviceId
  } yield mapToServiceStatus(exec, status)
}
```

and later

```
def getServiceStatus(id: String, tenantId: String)
: Future[Option[ServiceStatus]] = db
  .run(getServiceStatusCompiled(id, tenantId).result.transactionally)
  .map(_.headOption)
```

The problem is that not for all entries from table `execution` exists entry in table `serviceStatus`. I cannot modify table `execution` and add to it field `details` as it is only service specific.
When I run query in case when for entry from `execution` exists entry in `serviceStatus` all works as expected. But if there is no entry in `serviceStatus`, Future[None] is returned.
Question: Is there any option to obtain `status` in for comprehension as Option depending on existing entry in table `serviceStatus` or some else workaround?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `Future[None]` looks like a good answer if there is no `serviceStatus` record for that `id`, so what answer is it that you want to get? It looks like you are asking to get a status for an `id` that doesn't have a status, which is clearly not possible. If you want a default status then you can just use `getOrElse` on the `Option` but that doesn't seem to be quite what you want.

Comment: In the service status table, you don't have a mapping to case class

    def * = (serviceId, detail.?) <> (ServiceStatus.tupled, ServiceStatus.unapply)

The same situation is with `*` inside `ExecutionTable` you don't have an implementation for this method.

Comment: Thanks for all who responded.
Yes, code was not compiled, but I wanted to convey the crux of the problem.
And yes, Option[ServiceStatus] was good variant, but I could not figure out how can I get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, in case when join condition does not find corresponding record in the "right" table but the result should still contain the row from "left" table, left join is used. 
In your case you can do something like:

```
Execution
  .filter(...execution table filter...)
  .joinLeft(ServiceStatus).on(_.id===_.serviceId)
```

This gives you pair of

```
(Execution, Rep[Option[ServiceStatus]])
```

and after query execution:

```
(Execution, Option[ServiceStatus])
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!